# modifying messy JS code, ternary operators

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I want to modify a code so I can add a "virtual guitar notes" whenever user presses a keyboard key. The problem is I don't understand the following code:

```
        (b = c) ? b = "number" 
        == typeof b.which ? 3 : "number" 
        == typeof b.keyCode ? 2 : "number" 
        == typeof b.charCode ? 4 : 0 
        : (b = window.event, b = "number" == typeof b.keyCode ? 1 : 0);
```

and

```
        0 != b ? 
        ("number" == typeof c.modifiers ? a += "var c=f.modifiers;" 
        : "boolean" == typeof c.shiftKey ? a += "var c=f.shiftKey*4+f.ctrlKey*2+f.altKey;" 
        : Stop(), c.srcElement ? a += "var d=f.srcElement;" 
        : c.target ? a += "var d=f.target;" 
        : St()) 
        : St();
```

and

```
        DFunct || (d=10, f=11);
```

I understand that the last line translates to this:

```
        if(!DFunct){
           d=10;
           f=11;
        }
```

I need to make this using simple if else statements so I can make a note playing based on values pressed.

Comment: So what's the question? What does this code do or how to rewrite it so it's more clear?

Comment: sorry guys, yes I want to rewrite it using if else statements, the rest of the code is normal, just this part is like that.

Comment: [Here you go](http://pastebin.com/RS1bz1Lk). Takes all of two minutes in [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) using intentions.

Comment: @DCoder can you tell me how you did it using intentions? I installed phpstorm, but I can't find a way to use them. Does it let me convert line like I provided into normal if,else? Thanks

Comment: Check if the bundled "Javascript Intention Power Pack" plugin is enabled, and the intentions in Settings > Intentions > Javascript > Conditional operator are active. Then place your text cursor in the line where the ?: operator is, and press Alt-Enter to bring up the intentions list.

Comment: @DCoder, thanks man, worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First:

```
b = c;

if ( c ) {

    if ( typeof b.which === "number" ) {

        b = 3;

    } else {

        if ( typeof b.keyCode === "number" ) {

            b = 2;

        } else {

            if ( typeof b.charCode === "number" ) {

                b = 4;

            } else {

                b = 0;

            }

        }

    }

} else {

    b = window.event;
    b = typeof b.keyCode === "number" ? 1 : 0;

}
```

#### Second:

```
if ( b !== 0 ) {

    if ( typeof c.modifiers === "number" ) {

        a += "var c=f.modifiers;";

    } else {

        if ( typeof c.shiftKey === "boolean" ) {

            a += "var c=f.shiftKey*4+f.ctrlKey*2+f.altKey;";

        } else {

            Stop();

            if ( c.srcElement ) {

                a += "var d=f.srcElement;";

            } else {

                if ( c.target ) {

                    a += "var d=f.target;";

                } else {

                    St();

                }

            }

        }

}​ else St();
```

Comment: Thanks!! where did the x go!?

Comment: Nevermind. I found out that you were modifying `b`, and that the ternary operator *wasn't* stand-alone. I have the second one up now too.